# Use TensorFlow model to guess / predict values between 2 points

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

My question is something that I didn't encounter anywhere, I've been wondering if it was possible for a TF Model to determinate values between 2 dates that have real / validated values assigned to them.

I have an example :

Let's take the price of Nickel, here's it's chart the last week :

[image: Price of Nickel through time from the 17/11 to 24/11]

There is no data for the two following dates : 19/11 and 20/11
But we have the data points before and after.

So is it possible to use the datas from before and after these 2 points to guess the values of the 2 missing dates ?

Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible to create a machine learning model to predict the prices given a dataset of previous prices. Take a look at this [post](https://towardsdatascience.com/predicting-stock-prices-using-a-keras-lstm-model-4225457f0233) for instance. You would have to modify it slightly such that it predicts the prices in the gaps given previous and upcoming prices.

But for the example you gave assuming the dates are of this year 2022, these are a Saturday and Sunday, the stock market is closed on the weekends, hence there is not price of the item. Also notice that there are other days in the year where there is not trading occurring, think about holidays, then there also is not price of course.

Comment: Thank you a lot ! The exemple that I gave was as you said saturday and sunday but I also have some other days of the week (between monday and friday) where I don't have values sometimes, this is why I think it would be great to do it